# Finding density function of a conditioned function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(X, Y)$ be a point taken uniformly at random on the unit square
>   $[−1, 1]^2$. Let X|E be X conditioned on the event $E$ = ${\{X + Y \ge 0\}}$.
>
> Find the p.d.f. of X|E.

---

Now, the solution is given as follows:

[image]

As pointed out in the picture, I don't understand why divide by 4 for the numerator and by $\frac{1}{2}$ in the denominator. But here's my reasoning:

Divide by 4 because we're taking the area of the shaded region over the entire region which has area 4 as pointed out in the sketch.

Would appreciate if someone could explain it and perhaps point me to any good references/links out there! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the numerator, it is $2^2$, as you get the probability of $(X\leq x, X+Y\geq 0)$ by the area of the grey triangle divided by the area of the whole square.

For the denumerator, this is the area of the triangle on the right which represents the probability of $X+Y \geq 0$.

[image]

Solve this simple example: what is the probability that $X>0$ in this figure? It is $0.5$ by intuition, right? Mathematically, it is obtained by divining two areas; the area where $X>0$ (i.e., the right rectangle) and the whole area which represents all possibilities for $X$ (i.e., the whole square).

Comment: for the denominator, what do you mean by "area of triangle on the right"? I don't see any triangle on the right?

Comment: The one on the right of the drawn diagonal of the square

Comment: This one: http://imgur.com/8MY8TJc

Comment: ah! gotcha. thank you!